# Cannot concatenate with the link

Tags: php

Hello why is it that I cannot include in the link when I concatenate?

here is the code.

```
$mail->Subject = 'Verification Link';
 $mail->Body    = 'http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code='.$user_verificationCode;
 $mail->AltBody = 'http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code='.$user_verificationCode;
```

But the $userverifcation is not included in the link even when I concatenate it?
Here is the sample link: http://localhost/Mailer/verificationForgot.php?code= Zk8gIT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfZdL.png)

As you can see it is not included in the link? WHat should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in `$user_verificationCode`. You should use [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove it before append to URL.

```
$mail->Subject = 'Verification Link';
$mail->Body    = 'http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code='.trim($user_verificationCode);
$mail->AltBody = 'http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code='.trim($user_verificationCode);
```

Comment: When I use trim it is not recognizing the verification code

Comment: @EdoTensei how can you get it?

Comment: I mean the correct code is there but when I click it, it's echoing invalid code. But when I remove trim and just concatenate it and copy the link it's correct. But I don't know why it does not concatenate with the link.

Comment: @EdoTensei could you send me bold of them?

Comment: here. http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code= C45h8u

Comment: @EdoTensei it's still has space between `=` and `C`. is this the trimmed URL?

Comment: Ah sorry no. that's the link that was working

Comment: here is the trimmed link. http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code=ubF95y

I used this code 'http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code='.trim($user_verificationCode);

Comment: @EdoTensei the link looks good, which errors show when you said: "it is not recognizing the verification code"? Could you show me pls?

Comment: There's no error. It's just echoing invalid code when I use the trim method. But when I just concatenate it, it works.

Comment: @EdoTensei Could you paste both of them here? By trim and concatenate. I want to see which is different.

Comment: Concatenate: http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code= t9qvT4
                                                                        Trim: http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code=ubF95y

Comment: Concatenate: $mail->Body 'http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code='.$user_verificationCode;
Trim: $mail->Body 'http://localhost/Bloodsearch/user/verification.php?code='.trim($user_verificationCode);

Comment: @EdoTensei show me the code how you get `code` and verify it in `verification.php`.

Comment: sorry late reply here it is $code = $_GET['code'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_verificationCode=?";
      $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $code);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result=$stmt->get_result();
      $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
      $count=$result->num_rows;

Comment: here is the continuation of the code. if($count > 0){
        $user_isVerified='Yes';
        $user_verificationCode="";
        $sql="UPDATE users SET user_isVerified=?, user_verificationCode=? WHERE user_verificationCode=?";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user_isVerified, $user_verificationCode, $code);
        if($stmt->execute()){
          echo 'You have successfuly verified your account <br>';
          echo '<a href="login.php">Click this link to login</a>';
        }
      else
        echo 'Invalid verification code';

Comment: @EdoTensei It looks good. Do you check the difference between them on `$_GET['code']`?

Comment: yes I did. The concatenate works but the trim is not. But what I want is the verification code to be included when I click the link, not just copy it. I don't know why it won't concatenate with the link though.

Answer (score 0):

**you can also use a double quote instead of a single quote.**

```
$mail->Subject = 'Verification Link';
$mail->Body    = "http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code=$user_verificationCode";
$mail->AltBody = "http://localhost/Mailer/verification.php?code=$user_verificationCode";
```

Comment: This does not work it is still no included in the link